# What's the checksum algorithm for AnViz devices?

Tags: php, hex, fingerprint

I'm working on a way to directly connect to an AnViz biometric device(TC550, which uses TC400.dll methods) by TCP from Linux/PHP, however and thus I managed to get some strings for reading out of the device, I'm having a hard time to figure out the checksum which appears on the last 2 bytes of each code to send my own instructions to the device.

An example of a working code might be:

```
      function get_device_clock(){
      if(!$this->ip) return;
      if(!$this->open_socket()) return;
      $bytes = "A5";
      $bytes .= $this->fill_hex($this->id,8);
      $bytes .= "380000C4B8";

      $o = $this->comm($bytes);
      if(!trim($o)) return;
      $split = array();
      for($l = 0; $l < strlen($o); $l+=2){
          $split[] = substr($o,$l,2);
      }
      $year = hexdec($split[9]);
      if($year < 10) $year = "0" . $year;
      $year = "20$year";
      $month = hexdec($split[10]);
      if($month < 10) $month = "0$month";
      $day = hexdec($split[11]);
      if($day < 10) $day = "0$day";
      $hour = hexdec($split[12]);
      if($hour < 10) $hour = "0$hour";
      $min = hexdec($split[13]);
      if($min < 10) $min = "0$min";
      $sec = hexdec($split[14]);
      if($sec < 10) $sec = "0$sec";
      fclose($this->socket);
      return "$year-$month-$day $hour:$min:$sec\r\n";
  }
```

This will be sending A5 00 00 05 38 00 00 C4 B8 to the device at port 5010 causing it to reply with its time and date.

As this would enable realtime:

A5 00 00 00 05 33 00 0F FF FF FF FF 01 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 4E 37

This would list the last entries:

A5 00 00 00 05 40 00 02 01 19 FA FA

A5 00 00 00 06 3C 00 00 68 FE

A5 00 00 00 05 3C 00 00 A5 DB

Now the issue is, the last 2 bytes, C4 B8 at the first example, 4E 37 at the second, FA FA at the third, 68 FE and A5 DB on that where the ID is changed from 5 to 6, seams to be some sort of checksum. I'd tried all variants of common algorithms, even used Fsum Frontend, with all variants of byte ordering without success so far.

Also appears to have some variance in longer instructions, like these:

a5 00 00 00 05 73 00 29  01 00 00 00 00 17 ff ff ff 00 12 d6 93 00 58 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 6e 57

a5 00 00 00 05 73 00 29  01 00 00 00 00 01 10 00 01 3e eb 18 08 00 54 00  65 00 73 00 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 50 6f 54

Where in this case the checksum appears to be 40 6E 57 and 50 6F 54

Notes:
Requests seams to be composed of:

A5 + 4 bytes Serial# of the device + 1 byte Instruction code + variable length Content + 16/24 bits Checksum

You can get the SDK which generates this codes, tc400.dll, at [SDK BIO-OFFICE](http://www.bio-office.com.pt/p_software.php)

Any help to sort this out would be appreciated. TY in advance.

**UPDATE - Solved thanks to the Anviz Support Team **

Working code:

```
<?php 
 $crc_table = [
      0x0000,0x1189,0x2312,0x329B,0x4624,0x57AD,0x6536,0x74BF,0x8C48,0x9DC1,0xAF5A,0xBED3,0xCA6C,0xDBE5,0xE97E,0xF8F7,
    0x1081,0x0108,0x3393,0x221A,0x56A5,0x472C,0x75B7,0x643E,0x9CC9,0x8D40,0xBFDB,0xAE52,0xDAED,0xCB64,0xF9FF,0xE876,
    0x2102,0x308B,0x0210,0x1399,0x6726,0x76AF,0x4434,0x55BD,0xAD4A,0xBCC3,0x8E58,0x9FD1,0xEB6E,0xFAE7,0xC87C,0xD9F5,
    0x3183,0x200A,0x1291,0x0318,0x77A7,0x662E,0x54B5,0x453C,0xBDCB,0xAC42,0x9ED9,0x8F50,0xFBEF,0xEA66,0xD8FD,0xC974,
    0x4204,0x538D,0x6116,0x709F,0x0420,0x15A9,0x2732,0x36BB,0xCE4C,0xDFC5,0xED5E,0xFCD7,0x8868,0x99E1,0xAB7A,0xBAF3,
    0x5285,0x430C,0x7197,0x601E,0x14A1,0x0528,0x37B3,0x263A,0xDECD,0xCF44,0xFDDF,0xEC56,0x98E9,0x8960,0xBBFB,0xAA72,
    0x6306,0x728F,0x4014,0x519D,0x2522,0x34AB,0x0630,0x17B9,0xEF4E,0xFEC7,0xCC5C,0xDDD5,0xA96A,0xB8E3,0x8A78,0x9BF1,
    0x7387,0x620E,0x5095,0x411C,0x35A3,0x242A,0x16B1,0x0738,0xFFCF,0xEE46,0xDCDD,0xCD54,0xB9EB,0xA862,0x9AF9,0x8B70,
    0x8408,0x9581,0xA71A,0xB693,0xC22C,0xD3A5,0xE13E,0xF0B7,0x0840,0x19C9,0x2B52,0x3ADB,0x4E64,0x5FED,0x6D76,0x7CFF,
    0x9489,0x8500,0xB79B,0xA612,0xD2AD,0xC324,0xF1BF,0xE036,0x18C1,0x0948,0x3BD3,0x2A5A,0x5EE5,0x4F6C,0x7DF7,0x6C7E,
    0xA50A,0xB483,0x8618,0x9791,0xE32E,0xF2A7,0xC03C,0xD1B5,0x2942,0x38CB,0x0A50,0x1BD9,0x6F66,0x7EEF,0x4C74,0x5DFD,
    0xB58B,0xA402,0x9699,0x8710,0xF3AF,0xE226,0xD0BD,0xC134,0x39C3,0x284A,0x1AD1,0x0B58,0x7FE7,0x6E6E,0x5CF5,0x4D7C,
    0xC60C,0xD785,0xE51E,0xF497,0x8028,0x91A1,0xA33A,0xB2B3,0x4A44,0x5BCD,0x6956,0x78DF,0x0C60,0x1DE9,0x2F72,0x3EFB,
    0xD68D,0xC704,0xF59F,0xE416,0x90A9,0x8120,0xB3BB,0xA232,0x5AC5,0x4B4C,0x79D7,0x685E,0x1CE1,0x0D68,0x3FF3,0x2E7A,
    0xE70E,0xF687,0xC41C,0xD595,0xA12A,0xB0A3,0x8238,0x93B1,0x6B46,0x7ACF,0x4854,0x59DD,0x2D62,0x3CEB,0x0E70,0x1FF9,
    0xF78F,0xE606,0xD49D,0xC514,0xB1AB,0xA022,0x92B9,0x8330,0x7BC7,0x6A4E,0x58D5,0x495C,0x3DE3,0x2C6A,0x1EF1,0x0F78  
 ];
 /*************************************************
 * Calc CRC16 for Anviz TC-300,TC-400,TC-500,TC-550
 * 
 * @param binary $b
 */
 function tc_crc16($b){
  global $crc_table;
  $crc = 0xFFFF;
  for($l = 0; $l < strlen($b); $l++){
      $crc ^= ord($b[$l]);
      $crc = ($crc >> 8) ^ $crc_table[$crc & 255];
  }
  $res = strtoupper( dechex($crc) );
  return($res[2].$res[3].$res[0].$res[1]);
}  

/*****TEST AREA*****/
//$x = "A5000000033C0000"; //A5000000033C00003F90
 $x = "A5000000057300290100000000011000013EEB180800540065007300740000000000000000000000000001000000000050"; //A5000000057300290100000000011000013EEB1808005400650073007400000000000000000000000000010000000000506F54
echo tc_crc16(hex2bin($x)); 
?>
```

Comment: Where did you find php code to communicate/decipher data from the device?  Or did you write your own?  I'm trying to do the same thing in PHP, but all I can find is references to the DLL, which don't help because I'm in a linux environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consulted the R&D team and they informed me that the problem is with CRC16 checksum. Please download the CRC.rar file that contains CRC16Demo and let me know if that works better for you.
http://download.anviz.com/felix/CRC.rar

Kind Regards,

Anviz Support Team

http://anviz.com

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Worked like charm. I'll update my code with the working function in case some one else needs it.

Comment: Dear, Anviz Support Team

Could you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528983/anviz-ep300-unexpected-data-in-response-of-get-record-information-command-0x3c

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question/answer, but it was the only useful thing I could find relating to Anviz that wasn't for Windows, so I though I would update it with some more info in case anyone else needs it in the future:

### Command format

```
STXCH    (device code)    CMD（command)     LEN（data length)      DATA        CRC16
0xA5        4Bytes            1Byte              2Bytes         0-400Bytes    2Bytes
```

### Response format

```
STX CH   (device code)    ACK（response)       RET（return value)     LEN（data length)        DATA       CRC16
0xA5        4Bytes      1Byte（command+0x80）      1Byte                  2Bytes            0-400Bytes    2Bytes
```

### Description

1. Order of four byte CH：IDHH，IDHL，IDLH，IDLL；
2. CRC16 check means all data CRC16，order of two byte CRC16：CRCL CRCH；
3. When CH is 0，all devices connected will response to this command.
4. RET define as ：

   - define ACK_SUCCESS            0x00            // operation successful
   - define ACK_FAIL                   0x01            // operation failed
   - define ACK_FULL               0x04            // user full
   - define ACK_EMPTY              0x05            // user empty
   - define ACK_NO_USER            0x06            // user not exist
   - define ACK_TIME_OUT           0x08            //capture timeout
   - define ACK_USER_OCCUPIED      0x0A            //user already exists
   - define ACK_FINGER_OCCUPIED    0x0B            //fingerprint already exists
5. When the RET != ACK_SUCCESS, the DATA and LEN in the response data are always 0.

### Commands

I've uploaded the communications protocol document from Anviz tech support to https://github.com/benperiton/anviz-protocol